# JMS and portability

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, message-driven-bean

I'd like to know which are the best practices in order to achieve portability of MDBs.
I'm working on a application that uses a `ConnectionFactory` and both `Queue` and `Topic`. 
While testing the application on some application servers (mainly glassfish 3.1.2.2 and JBoss EAP 6.1) I found that a resource annotated like this:

```
@Resource(name="jms/myConnectionFactory", lookup="java:/jms/myConnectionFactory")
private ConnectionFactory myConnectionFactory;

@Resource(name="jms/myTopic", lookup="java:/jms/myTopic")
private Topic myTopic;
```

I've read somewhere that using `mappedName` property in `@Resource` is considered not portable since is AS-specific. But I'm struggling also with the aforementioned approach, actually working on Glassfish but not in JBoss. Is there a kind of truly portable approach to define JMS entities?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you change from WebSphere MQ API to general JMS for example, you might find that there are some *special* features in MQ which do not map to JMS.

If your source is already only using JMS, the only thing which really differs is the way to get your `ConnectionFactory`. On top of that I have not encountered any differences.

If you are using JMS queues without an application server (= without JNDI), normally only the ways to connect differ.

If you are using JMS queues in an application server (= using JNDI), normally only the JNDI name differs.

In case of MDBs, I prefer to configure the connection factory in the application server specific descriptor files (and not in the source) - to keep source and confguration separate. It's the data center's responsibility anyway to *configure* the application. It might help to build different packages for different environments and/or application servers.

Comment: I guess that keeping source and configuration separated is definitively a good approach. As you say, using AS-specific deployment descriptors helps a lot in keeping the source clean and truly portable. I have to say that it's really a pity not to use annotations for resources.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use JMS 2.0 annotations (but ofcourse on the JMS implementations that support it). JMS 2.0 defines many annotations and the ways to inject them that would help your situation.

The problem with JBoss is that it [will support these only in 8.0](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1288).